# prevent re-rendering when multiple component called from a single parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple component which has state change during its data collection from get api call, are called from a single component get re-render multiple times , Please help to avoid re-render when open this page

```
const MyData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState("");
  const getData = () => {
    axios.get("url").then(async function (response) {
      setData(response);
    });
  };
  const getData2 = () => {
    axios.get("url").then(async function (response) {
      setNewData(response);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getData2();
  });
  const NewData = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{data.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  const RewData = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{newData.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <NewData />
      <RewData />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Provide your current code, please.

Comment: add code plese help here , i am new to react native

Answer (score 0):

You provide no dependency array (undefined) to your `useEffect`. If the component's state changes, then the `useEffect` will be called again, which sets the state again, and so on.

You can provide an empty dependency array which will cause the `useEffect` to be called only once.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getData2();
}, []);
```

**Edit:** In response to the comments. You can prevent the screens content from rendering until the data has been fetched as follows.

```js
const MyData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState();

  const getData = () => {
    axios.get("url").then(async function (response) {
      setData(response);
    });
  };

  const getData2 = () => {
    axios.get("url").then(async function (response) {
      setNewData(response);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getData2();
  }, []);
  
  if (!data || !newData) {
     return null
  }
   
  const NewData = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{data.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const RewData = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{newData.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <NewData />
      <RewData />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: did it but , but when page opened it render multiple times , any solutions...

Comment: it will render three times. One on initial render, and one for each state change. What do you expect?

Comment: yes, as a result my app ui get blinked more than one times , i want to stop the blinking of my screen when we open the page...

Comment: Change the default value of your states from empty string to undefined and call `if (!data || !newData) { return null }` right before `const NewData...`.

Comment: This prevents rendering the screen until the data is fully loaded.

Comment: please tell where to write  ```if (!data || !newData){ return null }``` , not understand by right before ```const NewData...``` ,please help i am new to react native